# Jmeter performance metrices using plugin

Tags: memory, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter plugin to show cpu and memory performance related graphs. It's showing me the matrices based on threadgroup setting and rest client call to server using server agent. But I am not able to understand the matrices for the x and Y axis for cpu and memory. Please suggest how it's working.

Answer (score 1):

X axis: X axis value is cumulative value of current test duration , means in below graphs, test started 2 minutes and 5 minutes ago so the values is 00:02:05.

Example 1: If test started 30 minutes ago then x axis value is 00:30:00

Example 2: If test started 20 minutes and 20 seconds ago then x axis values is 00:20:20.

Y axis: Bit tricky , because in below graph "localhost Memory(*100)" utilization is 9000 means actual utilization is 90 % only this value is multiple by 100 (90*100=9000).

"Local host CPU (*1000)" means CPU is actual value (4) multiple by 1000.

The reason for multiple by 100 by Memory and 1000 by CPU is , network utilization is 30000.

[image]

In above graph Memory utilization is ~9000(~90*100) in above graph , actual utilization is ~90 only check below graph

[image]

Same thing for CPU utilization, check below[image]